# Is intersection casting possible in Kotlin?

Tags: casting, kotlin, type-inference

I have a method in Java like so:

```
public <T extends A & B> methodName(T arg, ...)
```

where A is a class and B is an interface.

In my kotlin class, I have another `variable` of type C, and I wish to achieve the following:

```
if (variable is A && variable is B) {
    methodName(variable, ...)
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Is it possible to properly cast `variable` so that it may be used as an argument without errors?

> Currently, the `variable` has a setter method, so smart casting isn't
>   available. However, I have also tested it with a local `val` and the
>   value is inferred to have type `Any` which doesn't help.

Comment: what's your kotlin version?

Comment: Here's a related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7304

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kotlin does not support intersection types. This causes `variable` to be smart cast to `Any`, because that is the common ancestor of `A` and `B`.

However, Kotlin does support generic type constraints. You can use this to constrain a type parameter to one or more types. This can be used on both methods and classes. This is the syntax for functions (the equivalent of your `methodName` in Kotlin):

```
fun <T> methodName(arg: T)
    where T : A,
          T : B {
    ....
}
```

You can use this to get around your problem by creating a class which extends both `A` and `B`, and then delegates the implementation of these types to your object. Like this:

```
class AandB<T>(val t: T) : A by t, B by t
    where T : A,
          T : B
```

You can now call `methodName` by changing your if-test to check if it is a `AandB<*>`:

```
if (variable is AandB<*>) {
    methodName(variable, ...)
}
```

You do need to wrap `variable` in a `AandB` somewhere though. I don't think you can do it if you don't have the type information for `variable` available anywhere.

Note: The `AandB` class does not implement `hashCode`, `equals` or `toString`. You could implement them to delegate to `t`'s implementation.

Note 2: This only works if `A` and `B` are interfaces. You can not delegate to a class.

Comment: As you mentioned and as I have tested, both A and B must be interfaces. However, my function's arg is of type T where T : [class], T : [interface]. Is there any way around that? Your method is very interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

As @marstran points out, the when clause is how you specify multiple bounds. Here's a link to the documentation about [upper-bounds](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#upper-bounds). It's worth mentioning that you **cannot** have multiple bounds if one of your bounds is a generic type parameter.

You mentioned that you tried testing with smart-casting:

> However, I have also tested it with a local val and the value is inferred to have type Any which doesn't help.

This is not the case for the current version of Kotlin (v1.4). You do **not** need to create an `AandB` class as you can use a `val` or local (captured) `var` to smart-cast to an intersection.

Here's an example (and [runnable version](https://pl.kotl.in/27R7a36Y_)):

```kotlin
interface I1 { fun one() = println("one") }
interface I2 { fun two() = println("two") }
class Both: I1, I2

val variable: Any = Both() // Starting with type 'Any'

if (variable is I1 && variable is I2) {
    // Type is now '(I1 & I2)' Smart-cast from Any
    variable.one()
    variable.two()
}
```

Here's a [link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/current-intersection-type-options-in-kotlin/20903) to more discussion and runnable example of Kotlin intersection types as of v1.4