# Type casting to satisfy multiple type constraints

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to typecast to satisfy multiple type constraints in kotlin?

Say I have the following case, but want to avoid type casting to class `C` (in case multiple classes implement `A` and `B`, or I don't know type `C`):

```
interface A
interface B

class C: A, B

fun <T> foo(bar: T) where T: A, T: B {

}
```

Is it possible to typecast to `A` and `B` simultaneously? Smart cast doesn't seem to allow this. Can I manually cast somehow?

```
val c = C()
foo(c) // works

val d: Any = c
if (d is A && d is B) {
    foo(d) // smart cast doesn't work here, compiler error
}

// Something like this maybe?
foo(d as A && B)
```

I know it's possible by creating a new interface that inherits from both `A` and `B`, and then use that, but that may not be possible if I don't control the classes in question.

Thanks

Comment: This question is no longer relevant, as a newer version of kotlin has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type has to explicitly implement the required interfaces and since `Any` cannot be both `B` and `A` (even though it implements both) simultaneously there has to be a third type, like `C`.

This similar question has a generic work around; [Is intersection casting possible in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448651/is-intersection-casting-possible-in-kotlin?rq=1)

so arbitrary types `T` which implement `A` and `B` can be recognized as such but `is` and `as` can't be directly composed with `&&` which makes it impossible to satisfy your functions type constraints without some kind of explicitly implementing wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Complete gist of answer: https://gist.github.com/MCeley/957aebbb27188855f1f31e9bc49137f4

Your original solution of using a combination of `&&` and `is` is valid starting in Kotlin 1.4.0.

Take the following example:

```
interface A
interface B

class AB : A, B

object App {
    // Generate an object that is an Any type
    fun genObj() : Any {
        return AB()
    }

    // Only print objects that are both A and B.
    fun <T> printObjType(
        obj : T
    ) where T : A, T : B {
        println("Object's type is ${obj.javaClass.simpleName}")
    }
}

fun main() {
    // Generate an object as an Any
    val obj = App.genObj()

    // Smart cast to A and B
    if(obj is A && obj is B) {
        // All type requirements met
        App.printObjType(obj)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can nest your casts and accomplish the same thing. Again, only valid starting in Kotlin 1.4.0.

```
// Any type
val obj = App.genObj()

if(obj is A) {
    if(obj is B) {
        App.printObjType(obj) // where obj : A, obj : B
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just retested this because of your answer, and it seems like the original question can compile just fine now. So you don't have to nest the checks, just do if (obj is A && obj is B)

Comment: @mhswtf You are correct that this works in versions of kotlin after 1.4.0. Will update my answer to reflect this.