# How to constrain generic type in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am creating a reactive stream that accepts Fruits

```
// PublishSubject is part of RxJava library. It accepts a generic T
class PublishSubject<T> {
   ...
}

val stream = PublishSubject<Fruit>.create()
```

However, I want it to accept only fruits that are edible

```
interface Edible {
   fun eat()
}
class Apple: Fruit, Edible
```

Edible behaviour interface can be applied to other foods (ice-cream, potato), however, I want only fruits that are edible.

```
val stream = PublishSubject<Fruit : Edible>.create()
```

Something like this, but this doesn't seem to work.

Can generics be constrained further upon instantiating without subclassing `PublishSubject`?

I could accept all edibles and do some hacky filtering, but that doesn't seem right
`PublishSubject<Edible>.create().filter(edible -> edible is Fruit)`

Comment: Unfortunately, Kotlin does not support intersection types. You could kinda get around it by using a wrapper type though, like I've outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453604/4137489

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where` keyword like this:

```
class PublishSubject<T> where T : Fruit, T : Edible {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do not want to subclass PublishSubject. It's part of RxJava library. (I just added the comment to my post)

Comment: I'm afraid that the only way to do it in Kotlin, is to use some kind of `EdibleFruit`